# angular ng-route doesn't find a template

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

Angular ng-route does not find a template but it is included in Dom. I am getting this error:

http://localhost/template/recipes Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

in html:

```
.
.
.
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div ui-view>
                loading...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
<script type="text/ng-template" id="/template/recipes">
    <div class="row">{{title}}<div>
</script>
```

routeConfig.js:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/recipes');

$stateProvider.state('recipes', {
        url: '/recipes',
        templateUrl: '/template/recipes',
        controller: 'recipesController'
    });
```

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to close your div tag in your template. Here is the working [plnk](http://plnkr.co/edit/SQYeZInX98dpzuaDddkb?p=preview).

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="/template/recipes">
    <div class="row">{{title}}</div>
</script>
```

**Edit**

I also updated the plnk to show the template name with and without an extension.

Comment: thanks, i do not add my template in wwwroot directory so it was unseable.

Comment: by the way, now controller wors perfectly but my content is still not displayed, if i keep then in script tags

Comment: Which content is not being displayed? Are you getting any errors?